# Get PopupWindow height which has been set to WRAP_CONTENT

Tags: android, view, kotlin

Here's my code:

```
val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
val popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.small_player, null)
val popupWindow = PopupWindow(popupView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT/*, focusable*/)
popupWindow.elevation = 1.0f
popupWindow.showAtLocation(window.decorView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, window.decorView.height)
val height = popupWindow.contentView.height //returns 0
```

I also tried with `popupView.height` but it returns 0 and with `popupWindow.contentView.layoutParams.height` that returned -1

So how can I get this height?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View's getWidth() and getHeight() returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/views-getwidth-and-getheight-returns-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common problem, your view isn't on the screen when you are trying to get its height

try this.

```
val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
val popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.small_player, null)
val popupWindow = PopupWindow(popupView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT/*, focusable*/)
popupWindow.elevation = 1.0f
popupWindow.showAtLocation(window.decorView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, window.decorView.height)

popupView.post{
    val height = popupWindow.contentView.height 
}
```

also check this for more [View's getWidth() and getHeight() returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/views-getwidth-and-getheight-returns-0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `View.getMeasuredHeight()` which gives you the actual height of the view.

The values you're getting now are the numerical representations used for MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT